# Apertium-caffeine

Tags: java, tradução

Baixei o .jar dessa biblioteca mas não tem nada, nenhum exemplo de como usar isso em java, alguem aqui já usou ou sabe como fazer para usar isso em um projeto java
baixei também o `lttoolbox-java` mas ta osso.

Answer (score 0):

O `apertium-caffeine.jar` não é uma biblioteca ao que parece, mas sim uma aplicação, pra usa-la faça isto no terminal ou CMD:

```
java -jar apertium-caffeine.jar
```

Download e wiki: http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Apertium-caffeine

Pra usá-lo offline é necessário baixar os idiomas desejados em  http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Language_pair_packages

Eu não achei nada sobre a lib ou API, mas e pode baixar a versão open-source aqui https://sourceforge.net/p/apertium/svn/46791/tree/trunk/apertium-caffeine/

Comment: olá @Guilherme Nasimento, o que eu to querendo é adicionar o .jar como uma biblioteca e usar como API no Studio, Isso seria possivel com ele, caso contrário voce me indicaria alguma outra para eu usar em meus projetos Java?
grato

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho acho que não leu direito a resposta, apertium-caffeine não é uma lib, adicionar no teu projeto provavelmente não terá efeito algum, se usa o netbeans o que você pode fazer é seguir o exemplo da versão open-source, veja: https://sourceforge.net/p/apertium/svn/46791/tree/trunk/apertium-caffeine/lib/ ... ainda sim mais tarde vou ver como criar um exemplo, qual IDE você usa?

Comment: android studio, mas o que quero é o seguinte, tenho um livro html em ingles, preciso que o usuario de outras linguas abram ele na sua lingua nativa, se estiver disponivel, mas tenho tambem esse texto em texto puro em uma tabela, dai, preciso de uma biblioteca ou api que faça a tradução